# Did Napoleon Wilson "reappear" as Snake Plissken?

Tags: character, escape-from-new-york, assault-on-precinct-13, escape-from-la

The character of [Snake Plissken](http://hero.wikia.com/wiki/Snake_Plissken) was created by John Carpenter and Nick Castle.  Plissken is the protagonist in [*Escape from New York*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082340/) and [*Escape from L.A.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116225/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt).

I recently noticed the following blurb on IMDb in regards to Plissken's character and another character created by John Carpenter.  From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074156/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv):

> Interestingly the character of Napoleon Wilson would essentially
>   reappear as Snake Pliskin in another John Carpenter film Escape from
>   New York (1981)

Am I misunderstanding this information?  **How could Napoleon Wilson from [*Assault on Precinct 13*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074156/?ref_=tttr_tr_tt) be "reappearing" as Snake Plissken?**

I know that homage is paid to Wilson in *Escape from L.A.*, when Snake Plissken asks commander Malloy for a smoke using the same line that Wilson uses repeatedly in *Assault on Precinct 13* of

> Got a smoke?

**Is there any evidence from filmmakers that the character of Napoleon Wilson reappeared as Snake Plissken?**

Comment: They might be talking about a mere *ideological* reappearance in the form of a similar character in that IMDb blurb (which actually has typos dimishing its official credibility). But interesting question nevertheless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plissken is referred to by Carpenter as a descendant of Wilson but I think this is meant more in **character refinement** or **spiritual descendant** terms rather than actual ancestry...but it's not impossible he meant it *literally*.

So not the same person but, arguably, related...one way or another.

Speaking to [**AintItCool.com**](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/67264)

> **AICN:** Snake is one of my favorite examples of a leading man anti-hero, so can we talk a little bit about how you guys created the very not dick-ish asshole that everybody still loves to this day?
>
> **Carpenter:** Look, **Snake Plissken is a direct descendant of Napoleon Wilson from Assault on Precinct 13**. He's cut from the same cloth. They are a combination of people. One is a guy I went to high school with who had a lot of the same characteristics and my own alter-ego. You combine my own alter-ego and this guy I knew then you get Snake Plissken. We added a bit of absurd romance to him. What's under that eyepatch? How did he get it? What has he been doing? Who is he really? We made him a mysterious character. So mysterious he was kind of a Man With No Name, an immitation of Eastwood.

Comment: Nice find!  Great interview by Carpenter!  It's so interesting that Carpenter said that about those two characters!  I wonder if that's why Plissken says the "Got a smoke" line in _Escape from L.A._.  +1 :)

Comment: I'm really confused about the DV on this answer.  This is a great answer with a source directly from the filmmaker.